# No tables found

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

After installing phpMyAdmin on a server I logged in with the username and pw of an existing db. But now I can see just the name of that db that already exists (and "information schema" db), but I can't see the tables inside the existing table. I do see the tables inside "information schema". Did I forget something while installing phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Also the hierarchy is server -> database -> table. (There cannot be tables inside tables.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the login credentials you used have permission to access the tables? Permissions can be assigned to individual tables and may prohibit that user from seeing them. Login as root (if you can) and check that the permissions on those tables and the database are appropriate for the login you want to use.

Comment: Hi,

I don't have root access. What I actually want to do is install other tables, which I may be able to do. The thing is I'm afraid something might happen to the existing tables that I can't see.

Comment: Your login should have access to a database, within which you should be able to create tables and manage them on your own. If you can't do this, you will need to contact your sysadmin and have them grant the permissions to your user. (Or at least create the tables for you.)